# (Some) applications not launching in Ubuntu using VNC on AWS EC2

Tags: 22.04, gui, vnc, aws

I am using an Ubuntu 22.04 installation on an AWS EC2 instance (VM). I have installed VNC server and I am accessing the system using VNC Viewer.

Initially, applications like Byobu Terminal and gedit were launching and working properly. However, Chromium and Firefox were not launching. I tried a few ways to get around this.

Now when I connect to the machine using VNC even Terminal and gedit are not launching. I am able to open the Desktop but when I click on Byobu terminal or gedit, nothing happens.

My `~/.vnc/xstartup` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey

vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &

autocutsel -fork
```

Comment: Found an alternative. Follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9v_NRE9Y7o) for accessing Desktop. Might help someone.
Credit to the poster of the video.